# SQL Multitable query with two sum statements

Tags: sql

great sql experts! :)
My boss wants month/year/day report of his employee's work. I figured most of SQL querys i need, but the last one is above my comprehension.

I have severas tables: Persons, Services, Plans and ProvidedServices. Table Plans contains inividual month plan for each person on each service. So i need a query that returns total value of services, provided by each person in particular time period on particular service AND summary value of planned work amount in same period on same service. Now i have something like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(BoRRenderedServices.ServiceCount), 
       BoREmployee.Name, 
       BoRServices.Service,
       SUM(BoRTargets.Amount)
FROM BoRRenderedServices, BoREmployee, BoRServices, BoRTargets
WHERE (BoRTargets.EmployeeID = BoREmployee.ID) 
AND (BoRTargets.ServiceID = BoRServices.ID) 
AND (BoRRenderedServices.Date BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2014-9-19') 
AND (BoREmployee.DepartmentID = 'cc42cac9-5ac7-4614-9b7b-ef931a9a132b')
AND (BoRRenderedServices.EmployeeID = BoREmployee.ID) 
AND (BoRRenderedServices.ServiceID = BoRServices.ID) 
AND (BoRRenderedServices.ServiceID = '0fbf68bf-ace8-4ecb-ba07-7049046c0215') 
GROUP BY BoREmployee.Name, 
       BoRServices.Service
```

But this query makes double sum, it summarizes amounts of provided services twice, the same is for plans. I mean, each time it founds provided service maching the WHERE conditions - it summarizes plans too, instead of adding only provided service into first sum statement.

Person 1, provided Service1 three times in August 1st , one time in August 3rd, and 4 times in July 4th. The plan for Person1 for August is three, and for July is four.

Desired output: 
`--------------Plan       Fact
 Service1       1----------1
 Service2       1----------2 
 Service3       1----------3`
Actual output: 
`--------------Plan       Fact
 Service1       3----------3
 Service2       3----------6 
 Service3       3----------9`

Comment: Can you post actual data and desired output ? What DB do you have MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, what version ? Also you can post example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Old-School JOIN's have been decrepit for about 20 years now, please use JOIN keyword.

Comment: Provide an example on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Max I am using SQL Server 9. I cant find the way to place table into comment to illustrate desired and actual output... :'(

Comment: [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @Max http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09586/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the query.
You can create as view or your sql database.

Check on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72bce/13)

```
with tbl1 
as
(
  SELECT 
        b.EmployeeId
       ,b.ServiceId
       ,c.Service
       ,d.Name
       ,Sum(b.Amount) Amount
FROM 
    BoRTargets b
        inner join BoRServices c
    on b.ServiceId = c.Id
        inner join BoREmployee d
    on b.EmployeeId = d.Id
WHERE (b.Date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-26') 
 AND (d.DepartmentID = 'cc42cac9-5ac7-4614-9b7b-ef931a9a132b')
GROUP BY b.EmployeeId, b.ServiceId, c.Service, d.Name
)
,

tbl2
as
(
  SELECT 
      a.EmployeeId
     ,a.ServiceId
     ,c.Service
     ,d.Name
     ,SUM(a.ServiceCount) ServiceCount
FROM 
    BoRRenderedServices a 
        inner join BoRServices c
    on a.ServiceId = c.Id
        inner join BoREmployee d
    on a.EmployeeId = d.Id
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM BorTargets b 
     where (a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId and a.ServiceId = b.ServiceId)
     AND (b.Date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-26'))
 AND (d.DepartmentID = 'cc42cac9-5ac7-4614-9b7b-ef931a9a132b')
GROUP BY a.EmployeeId, a.ServiceId, c.Service, d.Name
)

select coalesce(a.Service, b.Service) Service, coalesce(a.Name, b.Name) Name, a.Amount, b.ServiceCount
from tbl1 a full join tbl2 b
 on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId 
 and a.ServiceId = b.ServiceId
```

Comment: Mark as the answer if is ok.

Comment: No. It does'nt work either. The same result, if I add some more rendered services. Look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72bce/1, it still double summarizes Amount column.

Comment: I added three rows into table A.

Comment: I mean, i need to summarize Amount column and ServiceCount coulumn values separately in one query...